# Convert only some pages from PDF to TIF with xpdf

Tags: xpdf

I'm using this command to convert a PDF to a TIF image on stdout:

```
convert -density 300 -depth 8 -compress lzw my.pdf tif:-
```

If the PDF has multiple pages, how to convert only the first page?

Comment: I think that convert is an [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#cmdline) command.

Comment: In this case it is part of xPdf package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Append the page number to the input filename with array-like syntax:

```
convert -density 300 -depth 8 -compress lzw my.pdf[0] tif:-
```